# help! rtmp support for iphone using rtmp-dump

Tags: iphone, audio, streaming, rtmp

I'm working on an iphone app which needs to do live radio streaming via rtmp protocol. i have been banging my head to find out a solution. all i know is that i should be able to use rtmp-dump. but i'm newbie to iphone dev, so cry out to ask for anyone which can give me a help on this?

any response is much appreciated.

Stephen

Answer (score 1):

read this line

Real Time Messaging Protocol (RTMP) was initially a proprietary protocol developed by Macromedia for streaming audio, video and data over the Internet, between a Flash player and a server. Macromedia is now owned by Adobe, which has released the specification of the protocol for public use.

this is specifically for communication between of Flash player and server , with iPhone the flash player is not supported.

If you want to play live streaming video there are other options and you have to use that thing but not RTMP other wise apple may can reject your application

here is the link which had such discussion

http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/13880-rtp-stream-video-audio.html

Hope this is useful to you